# Image viewer that can display all ICO sizes in a file

Tags: software-recommendation, icons, image-processing, file-format, image-viewers

What are the image viewers available in Kubuntu that are able to display all ICO sizes in a file?

In Windows 7 Picture Viewer, I can use PAGE UP / PAGE DOWN to navigate on the "mipmaps" (or whatever it's called) of an ICO file. It seems I can't do that on EOG, Gwenview, or even Pinta.

I'm looking for a viewer, but if you know of an editor that allows to edit each size independently, that would be nice too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GIMP will do it (I have version 2.10.18, but perhaps an earlier version can work as well).
[image]

Comment: Ah I see, thanks! It's a weird choice to just treat the pages like layers, using the largest size, but hey, it works I guess! I'll mark this as accepted. Though it'd be better if each layer had a different size (or zoom) to facilitate design.

Answer (score 2):

Generally I like to use online applications when there isn't a concern about security and privacy. You can search on the Internet for an **"online ico icon viewer"**. The one I just met seems to work properly:

> https://redketchup.io/icon-editor

Answer (score 1):

I use [XnView MP](https://www.xnview.com/en/xnviewmp/).

It's closed source, but is an excellent tool for image viewing - among many other things, such as batch editing or some basic image manipulation.

In this picture, I have opened a .ico:

[image: .ico opened with XNView]

As you can see, it just shows the largest size.

If I click on 'View' and turn on 'Icon Snapshot' then I get to see all the different sizes, like this:

[image: .ico opened with icon snapshot enabled]

Alas, I do not see anywhere in it to edit each of them individually. It may be in there, but I'm not seeing it. XnView has a whole lot of features and has a Linux version that's easy to install. Just scroll down at the above link and you'll find a version that works for you.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to avoid installing closed source that's not available as sandboxed snap or flatpak, but I'll upvote your answer. Thanks!